# Usar 2 tipos de navegação Drawer e BottomTab ao mesmo tempo

Tags: android, react-native, navigation-drawer

Olá,
Estou meio confuso em relação as rotas do react-native, digo quando preciso usar 2 tipos de rotas na mesma tela. Aqui vai minha tentativa até agora:

```
export default (isSigned = false) =>
  createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
      {
        Sign: createSwitchNavigator({
          SignIn,
          SignUp,
        }),
        App: createBottomTabNavigator({
          Dashboard,
          Profile,
          Settings,
        }),
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: isSigned ? 'App' : 'Sign',
      },
    ),
  );
```

Cheguei até aqui onde consigo usar o TabNavigator ou Drawer, não os 2 juntos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após alguns minutos de pesquisa resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
export default (isSigned = false) =>
  createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
      {
        Sign: createSwitchNavigator({
          SignIn,
          SignUp,
        }),
        App: createBottomTabNavigator({
          Dashboard: {
            screen: createDrawerNavigator({
              Dashboard,
              Profile,
              Settings,
            }),
          },
          Profile: {
            screen: createDrawerNavigator({
              Dashboard,
              Profile,
              Settings,
            }),
          },
          Settings: {
            screen: createDrawerNavigator({
              Dashboard,
              Profile,
              Settings,
            }),
          },
        }),
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: isSigned ? 'App' : 'Sign',
      },
    ),
  );
```